# Change class of another element using template reference variable

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I have this component template:

```
<div id="one" (click)=""></div>
<div id="two" #two></div>
```

What should I put inside `(click)=""` to assign the second div some class. I know it can be done inside component code, but is there a way to do it directly in template?

Answer (score 4):

```
(click)="two.className = 'someClass'"
```

or

```
(click)="two.classList.add('someClass')"
```

See also [Change an element's class with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-class-with-javascript)

Answer (score -1):

```html
<div id="one" (click)="document.getElementById('#two').classList.add('soemClass')"></div>
<div id="two" #two></div>
```

This may help you!